# How to pass the variable from views.tpl.php to page.tpl.php?

Tags: drupal-7, view

I need pass variable from views-view-unformatted.tpl.php to page.tpl.php.

So the code of views-view-unformatted.tpl.php:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
    <?php if(condition): ?>
      <?php $my_var = array('val_1','val_2','val_3'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and in result I want something like this:

```
...
<div class="footer">
  foreach ($my_var as $val) {
    print $val . <br>;
  }
</div>
...
```

It is possible to print in page.tpl.php the variable generated in the views-view-unformatted.tpl.php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  .. my code here ..
}
```

from [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/setting-up-variables-for-use-in-a-template-preprocess-and)